# How to get back on foot with Ogre's Owl's Hunt?

Tags: street-fighter-x-tekken

When [Ogre](http://tekken.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Ogre) gets knocked down, it's possible to get him back on foot with the Owl's Hunt attack.  I do it frequently, but I don't really understand how: it doesn't look like the same move than the one used for the attack (forward Z + kick).  Any idea ?